# MS Excel VBA find cell with string value

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a hard time figuring out the best way to find and replace a string value in a column of over 4,000 rows where the value should be numeric.

The customer collects several workbooks and wants to consolidate them. I have that working but one particular column should be a numeric values but occasionally the reporting system will dump out a extraneous string character in that column.

Here is what I am doing right now with VBA

```
For Each r in rng
if not IsNumeric(r.value2) then r.value=null
Next r
```

As you can imagine, this for/next loop takes a while to run.  There has got to be a better way to deal with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Fred

PS: I have toyed with .Find and .Replace but couldn't make them work.

Comment: Can you use =VALUE(A1)?

Comment: I just tried this on 20k rows and it ran quite quickly.  Is there something else going on in the code?

Comment: @mrbungle The code provided is the exact code. Nothing else in between. I am running it from Access, I don't think this would be causing a time issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use the specialcells feature

```
on error resume next 'in case there are no string cells
rng.specialcells(xlCellTypeConstants,2).clear
on error goto 0
```

Comment: Specialcells and autofilter are two great tools to avoid loops. Saves quite a bit of processing time occasionally.

Comment: Good to see you back Thomas.

Comment: Life's been busy, but I do need to keep my excel skills challenged.